# Visual Studio: The dbType NvarChar is invalid for this constructor (Team Foundation Server.)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have a web project ( css , html , angularJS and more JS libS) project hosted in Microsoft TFS and it been working fine so far but today when We tried to get latest on the project We keep getting the folowing error **"The dbType NvarChar is invalid for this constructor"**. If We try to get latest on single item which doesn't have pending changes, It works perfectly but as soon as We try getting latest on multiple items which at least one of them has pending changes the error occurs.

I tried disconnect/reconnect TFS , Clear VS Cache (local and Roaming) but all those operations did not help.

[image]

Comment: Show the code where the error occurs.  Which line...

Comment: This is not happening in code btw. it's when I try to get latest on Microsoft Team Foundation Server (using Visual Studio 2013 ) my code builds perfectly

Comment: I am getting the same error...any update?

Comment: I am getting the same error on 4 projects. 2 of which were not changed and worked fine. Problem occurs both on server and local computer. I assume tfs was done but this problem still exists for 3 days now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's an issue with VSO.

For now, I've found a workaround:

- go to `Source Control Explorer`
- do a `Get Latest Version` from there

It should work without a problem.

Comment: This works but It doesn't solve the problem , I believe we should be able to get latest from the Solution explorer right-away without going to Source Control Explorer.

Comment: You still have this problem? I thought it was a temporary issue with VSO. This morning everything was working fine for me & I could get latest straight from the Solution Explorer.

Comment: So As @Marius mentioned this was temporary , on that the day I followed his procedure getting latest from Source Controller Explorer , The next day I restart setting and user data on my visual Studio , and everything went back to normal. So I assume it was temporary wit VSO

Answer (score 0):

If you get a new workspace it will allow you get the latest changes. But, best we come up with so far.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was gone after I checked in my own pending changes and resolved the workspace.

So, at least this is what worked for me:

1. Getting `"The dbType NvarChar is invalid for this constructor"` error when trying to get latest from TFS.
2. Check in my pending changes.
3. After a successful gated check-in, click `Resolve Workspace`.
4. The DbType problem is gone!

HTH

Comment: Where can we find the `Resolve Workspace` option (in Visual Studio 2013)?

Answer (score 0):

For us, this is caused by a conflicting Entity Framework edit in the project file. In our scenario, a table has been added to the EF map in source control and the project file updated by developer 1. If developer 2 has an edit to the project file, and does a get latest version, the error is thrown. If you undo your changes to the project file, the get latest works without throwing the error dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check in your pending changes and resolve the conflicts (Also check in the changes after conflicts resolved). Then get latest feature should works.